# PyInstaller app gets caught by SmartScreen

Tags: python, pyinstaller, smartscreen

I made a program for people at work that simply takes csvs, converts them, and turns them into a csv that can be read by a different program and I have made the program in Python. Everyone here uses Windows so I originally used py2exe to make an exe and it worked fine for everyone.

Recently, I made some changes to the code to use the newest Python version which py2exe does not support so I used pyinstaller which worked great. However, when I passed it on to a few people at the office to test it, Windows SmartScreen caught it and the Anti-Virus program quarantined it for 3 hours. Obviously this is not ideal. What can I do to not make SmartScreen catch it? And why would py2exe not trigger the same warnings?

Answer (score -1):

SmartScreen show this warning for executables that are not popular and unfortunately Microsoft does't give a certain number of downloads to SmartScreen stop triggering out.